# Heat inflow where $u(x,y,z) = 2y^2+2z^2$ , $K=6.5$ through surface $S$ $y^2+z^2=6, \space x\in[0,4]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, heat-equation, surface-integrals

I just want to confirm that my calculation is right with the following problem.

I want to find the rate of heat flow where $u(x,y,z) = 2y^2+2z^2$ , $K=6.5$ through surface $S$... $y^2+z^2=6, \space x\in[0,4]$

I know that

$$\int \int_S -K\nabla \vec u\cdot d\vec S$$

is the usual heatflow equation, but the problem asks us to find the heatflow inwards the surface so the answer will simply be the opposite of this expression.

Without nice shortcuts or anything, I parametarized the surface using $y = \sqrt{6}\cos{\theta}$, $z = \sqrt{6}\sin{\theta}$ and $x=x$ so

$$\nabla \vec u = <0,4\sqrt{6}\sin{\theta},4\sqrt6\cos{\theta}>$$

and

$$\vec n = <0,\sqrt6\cos{{\theta},} \sqrt{6} \sin{\theta}>$$

where the dot product is simply $24$.

So, the inflow simply becomes

$$K(24)A$$

where $A$ is the lateral area of the cylinder, which is $8\sqrt{6}\pi$ .

I get the solution $1248\sqrt{6}\pi$, but can anyone else confirm that I got the right number?

Comment: Just an FYI. You say, "but the problem asks us to find the heatflow inwards the surface so the answer will simply be the opposite of this expression." Whether or not you negate the flux integral depends on your parameterization of the surface. If your surface parameterization is $r(u,v)$ and $r_u\times r_v$ happens to point inward then there is no need to negate the flux integral. (Assuming you proceed formally and assign $n=\frac{r_u\times r_v  }{ ||r_u\times r_v|| }$) It turns out your parameterization induces an outward normal so negating the flux integral is appropiate in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I am used to considering outward surfaces only and am not used to concepts such as these related to physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla \vec u = <0,4\sqrt{6}\cos{\theta},4\sqrt6\sin{\theta}>$. You just have a typo as your reversed the order of $y$ and $z$ component when you wrote but your dot product is correct.

$\vec n = \ <0, \sqrt6\cos{{\theta},} \sqrt{6} \sin{\theta}>$ is radially outward vector but given the question we will choose $\vec n = <0, - \sqrt6\cos{{\theta},} - \sqrt{6} \sin{\theta}>$.

If you do your calculation using outward pointing vector, you will have to just reverse the sign in the end as you rightly said.

Now this is where you have a mistake. Your normal vector is not normalized  so multiplying again by surface area will give a wrong result.

Since you have parametrized the surface as $r(x,\theta) = <x, \sqrt6 \cos\theta, \sqrt6 \sin\theta>$

$dS = \vec{n}\ dx \ d\theta $ ($\vec{n} = r'_{x} \times r'_{\theta}$). So your integral is simply,

$\displaystyle 24K \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{4} dx \ d\theta = 1248 \pi$

Comment: Just to clarify, my normalized version of $\vec n$ should actually be $\vec n / \sqrt{6}$ in this case?

Comment: I actually think I figured out what I have been doing wrong.  Every time I did $\vec n$  I was not aware that $\vec n$ had to be a unit normal vector.

Comment: @hyg17 that is correct. You will have to divide by $\sqrt6$ to make it unit normal. I usually do not normalize as it cancels out in the integral.

Comment: Just to complete this point, I do not think you would be doing it wrong all along otherwise all your answers would have been wrong. I think when you do the integral, it would be coming correct. For example, if the vector field was different and the dot product was not a constant, say it was $24 \cos^2 \theta$, how would you proceed? You would do the integral and then your answer would be correct. But here you did not do the integral. You instead tried to multiply by surface area directly and you cannot do that unless the dot product was with unit normal.

Comment: Please think through this with couple of examples. Let me know if any questions.